# Android : AdMob onClickListener

Tags: android, click, admob, banner

I display into my android application **AdMob's** banners. I would like that when the user click on the banner it gone. I have try the code `AdView.setOnClickListener` but it not work...

EDIT : this is the code

```
private void visual_banner(){
//##### Pubblicità #####
        //Create the adView    
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e5bed604ebf8");   
        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given    
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"    
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_ads_streaming);    
        // Add the adView to it    
        layout.addView(adView); 
        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad    
        adView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                adView.destroy();
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        //### FINE PUBBLICITA'
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to show us what you've tried, so we'll see if there's a problem.

Comment: I have edit my question and insert the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can help you with AdWhirl adds.

I have seen sources and have done next:

```
public class AdWhirlLayoutCustom extends AdWhirlLayout {

public AdWhirlLayoutCustom(Activity context, String keyAdWhirl) {
    super(context, keyAdWhirl);
}

public AdWhirlLayoutCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

// We intercept clicks
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean result = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Click!
        break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: If you intercept the click event and hide the ad though, you won't get credit for the ad click, and that kind of defeats the purpose of showing ads in the first place.

Answer (score 12):

Try using AdMob's [adListener](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#android-adlistener) to listen for events.

```
public interface AdListener {
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad);
  public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, AdRequest.ErrorCode error);
  public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad);
  public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad);
  public void onLeaveApplication(Ad ad);
}
```

Have your class implement the listener, and then add the listener to the adView:

```
adView.setAdListener(this);
```

Implement the onDismissScreen event, which occurs once your app resumes control after handling the ad click.  At this point, you can remove the AdView, and you will have gotten credit for the click.

```
@Override
public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad) {
  if (adView != null) {
    adView.destroy();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement onAdLeftApplication() of AdListener interface. This method is called when an ad leaves the application (e.g., to go to the browser).

adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication ()
        {
           //Do your stuff
        }
    }
```

});

For more info check below link
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener.html#onAdLeftApplication()

Answer (score 1):

I agree with above all the answer but i am just extending the answer. I have done like below

Load the ad in `AdView` as below

```
AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .addTestDevice("your device id")
                    .build());
```

Now next set the ad listener on that `adView`. Take one global boolean variable like `isClicked` so whenever user will click on ad and switch on that page `onAdLeftApplication()` method will called so make that variable as true. When user will click on ad then redirect to that ad page so current app will goes to onPause state.

```
adView.setAdListener(adListener);

com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener adListener = new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            super.onAdLeftApplication();
            isClicked = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked() {
            super.onAdClicked();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdImpression() {
            super.onAdImpression();
        }
    };
```

Now whenever user will come back to the current app activity `onResume()` method is called, So implement your other stuff will be there or as below

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (isClicked){
            isClicked = false;
            // do your other stuff whatever you want;
        }
    }
```