# AdMob: display advertisement in WebView

Tags: android, webview, admob

I use `AdMob` service to display advertisement in my android app.

I need to display advertisement using `WebView` instead of opening external web browser for it.

Overriding `onLeaveApplication()` method in `AdListener` doesn't help, external application is opened anyways after running method code.

Any solution?

Comment: If you can use AdWhirl than look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665237/android-admob-onclicklistener)

Comment: Yury, did you managed to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean when you click on your ad it opens in a separate browser window? you would like it open inside the same webview?

then you just need to add a shouldoverrideurlloading. something like this:

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {



            if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
                 return false;


            }



             // Otherwise allow the OS to handle it
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
             startActivity( intent );
```

EDIT: sorry, this is only for the actual webview you are using in your app. since admob ads are displayed in their own little banner (which is essentially a webview too) it doesnt make sense to load that webpage into the banner. therefore a browser window has to pop up. may i ask why that is so important to you? I dont think it can be easily realized, meaning its not really possible.

Comment: Well, let's assume that banner is already loaded. After that user clicks it, and advertisement url is opened in external web browser. What I need is to open it inside internal WebView. Your solution wouldn't help because, as far as I'm concerned, there's no way to get an instance of WebView associated with AdView (and so you can't load your own WebViewClient), and there's no way to get advertisement url before it's actually displayed in external browser.

Comment: yes. that is why i said in my edit that i think it is close to impossible. sorry man