# Want to check if my banner was clicked - admob

Tags: android

i've a added a banner using AdMob,

I want to check if it was clicked.

this is my code:

```
public class CalcActivity extends Activity {
private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc);
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a150b2362fba949");
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.calcL);
    layout.addView(adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}
```

I've tried the adView.SetAdListener method, but it doesn't seem to have an "OnClick" method.

any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665237/android-admob-onclicklistener/48761987#48761987

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put a View above ads and put a onClickListener without stop propagation on event.

EDIT :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
//Your layout here
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"         
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="a150240343d3227"
                         ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
<View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/myidview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Not sure it's work i don't have test do you see what i mean now ? Put click listener to myidview.

Comment: What do you mean by " put a View above ads"? can you give an example please?

Comment: Ok, i'm trying to that, but when i try to add the AdView in the XML i get this: java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log  and

Comment: the log : java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.ads.AdView.onMeasure(SourceFile:670)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)

Answer (score 0):

> delete all the code related to the ad in your activity file and post this code to your corresponding xml file

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       ads:adUnitId="a150b2362fba949"
                       android:layout_above="@+id/tv1a"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER"
                       ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

For those who still didnt know how to:

Its using AdListener

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
               Toast.makeText(BannerAdListener.this, "Back to app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
               Toast.makeText(BannerAdListener.this, "Error loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
               Toast.makeText(BannerAdListener.this, "Left app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
               Toast.makeText(BannerAdListener.this, "Sumthin sumthin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
               Toast.makeText(BannerAdListener.this, "Ad Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            });
```